# Python Spider ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I am performing a crawling process with python-scrapy. After a random number of iterations that crawls to next page (usually between 400-500), the spider fails, raising `ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))`.

I've tried several solutions like using headers with random user-agent and none referers or proxy as recommended in some other posts but the spider keeps failing.

The raised error is:

```
018-06-08 16:05:34 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www... > (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...

ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))
2018-06-08 16:05:34 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

The iteration code part looks like:

```
if self.counter <= self.limit:

            ua = UserAgent(cache=False)
            User_agent = ua.random
            headers =  {
            'User-Agent': User_agent,
            'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4',
            'Referer':response.request.headers.get('Referrer', None),
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }

            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True, headers=headers)
```

Any idea of why this is happening?

Solutions could be oriented towards avoiding the error or maybe restarting the spider somehow after the error is raised and resuming the crawling process.

Answer (score 0):

`BadStatusLine` is raised because the host is detecting the spider as a bot, and disconnecting it on purpose. Since you are already specifying the `UserAgent`, maybe you can use a headless browser like `PhantomJS` to simulate a browser.

There is a also a middleware that does this: [scrapy-webdriver](https://github.com/brandicted/scrapy-webdriver)